# Linear independence of vectors in Graph Theory

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, matrices

I have poste this question on StackExchange but there were no takers - would I be luckier on this site?

Most of this is well known, so let me just restate the corresponding Math:

Given a connected, directed, simple (no loops, no parallel edges) graph with $m$ vertices and $n$ edges, one first builds its $m$ by $n$ incidence matrix marking (by $1$ or $-1$ for 'in' or 'out', $0$ otherwise) incident edges of each vertex. One row of this matrix is then deleted; since the matrix is of rank $m-1$ (the only liner combination of rows yielding the zero vector is their sum, as each column has only two nonzero elements, equal to $1$ and $-1$), the resulting matrix (say $K$) consists of linearly independent rows (each row is a vector representing a 'star' - incident edges to a single vertex).

One then finds all fundamental cycles of the corresponding undirected graph (yet, the cycles are oriented, following one of the two possible directions); one can prove that there are exactly $n-m+1$ such cycles. The result is then converted into a similar, $n-m+1$ by $n$ matrix (say $C$) whose rows indicate which edges are a part of the corresponding cycle ($1$ when the cycle's orientation agrees with the graph's orientation, $-1$ when not, $0$ otherwise). It's again easy to prove that the rows of $C$ are linearly independent (each cycle has a unique edge found in no other cycle); each of them is also orthogonal to every row of $K$.

This implies that the two matrices, when joined to create an $n$ by $n$ matrix, create a single REGULAR (non-singular) matrix - no problem there.

What I need to show next (which I cannot find in literature and failed to do so myself) is that this remains true even after each column of $C$ has been multiplied by an arbitrary (one for each column) positive number (equivalent to assigning weights to edges).

A secondary (more difficult) question is: can some of these numbers be $0$ and still yield a regular matrix? The answer is yes, and my conjecture is that this is the case whenever the corresponding 'zero' edges (or their subset) do not form a cycle. Again, how do I prove that?

Comment: "Regular" = "non-singular"?

Comment: Your $m$ and $n$ seem to be mixed up in a couple of places.

Comment: An error: there are $m-n+1$ such cycles. So the non-singular matrix you get in the end is $m\times m$, not $n\times n$. What you've done is found a basis for the cut space and the cycle space of the (matroid of the) graph, and it's well known that the sum of cut and cycle spaces is the whole edge space.

Comment: Whoops just noticed comment of @GordonRoyle says same thing.

Comment: Please include a link to the question on math.stackexchange (if that's where you posted it, Honza).

Comment: I think it is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4003961/linear-independence-of-vectors-related-to-graph-theory

Comment: Sorry about my careless and embarrassing $n$ versus $m$ confusion - hopefully fixed now.